# Xcode Swift error by casting my own collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I tried to create my own collectionViewCell. But by casting it in the cellForItemAt indexPath method it throws an error.
I don´t know why.
i hope you can help me.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var testCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        self.testCollectionView.register(TestCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "testCell")
    
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.testLabel.text = "Hihi Test!"
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
    }
}
```

This is the collectionViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class TestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var testLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(testLabel)
        
        testLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        testLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And this is the error by starting the app:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try renaming `TestCollectionViewCell` to `CollectionViewCellTest` (probably won't work, but I think I remember something about not naming classes with "Test" in front)

Comment: You could have updated your previous question instead of creating a new one. Though. Is `TestCollectionViewCell` pure code, or it is set with a Xib? Do you collectionView IBOutlet has a cell inside it in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes. TestCollectionViewCell is only Code (see code in the appendix). And yes inside my storyboard i have a test cell.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately to rename the file doesn´t work.

Comment: You have a testCell inside your collectionView in the Storyboard? Did you set its reuseIdentifier? Its class? If `TestCollectionViewCell` is pure code, just remove it  the extra cell from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First, register your cell into `viewDidLoad` method like that:

```swift
testCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TestCollectionViewCell", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "testCell")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your Answer! Unfortunately it doesn´t work by me. It throws this error:Thread 1: "Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/timmeyerdiercks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6E88FC2B-FD4D-459D-AAC8-E75BB959B603/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EBF5B5AF-1267-4602-99DE-D54FDE617EF2/CollectionViewTestApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'CollectionViewCellTest'"